# How to use an ArrayList java object passed into the Rhino javascript engine?

Tags: javascript, rhino

The following data:

```
sku=[111222]
```

is being passed in as an argument to a javascript function being invoked in the Rhino javascript engine.

On the java side (where the data originates) this means that a String key of "sku" is mapped to an ArrayList with one String "111222" inside it.

Once this goes over to the Rhino side, I have no idea how to make use of this as a javascript object. For example: How do I even do something as simple as fetching the 111222 value on the JS side?

I decided to spit out what a key/value dump of this object looked like on the JS side and this is what I got:

```
sku=

empty: false

indexOf: function indexOf() {/*
int indexOf(java.lang.Object)
*/}

notifyAll: function notifyAll() {/*
void notifyAll()
*/}

removeAll: function removeAll() {/*
boolean removeAll(java.util.Collection)
*/}

trimToSize: function trimToSize() {/*
void trimToSize()
*/}

containsAll: function containsAll() {/*
boolean containsAll(java.util.Collection)
*/}

contains: function contains() {/*
boolean contains(java.lang.Object)
*/}

equals: function equals() {/*
boolean equals(java.lang.Object)
*/}

notify: function notify() {/*
void notify()
*/}

subList: function subList() {/*
java.util.List subList(int,int)
*/}

class: class java.util.ArrayList
set: function set() {/*
java.lang.Object set(int,java.lang.Object)
*/}

isEmpty: function isEmpty() {/*
boolean isEmpty()
*/}

add: function add() {/*
void add(int,java.lang.Object)
boolean add(java.lang.Object)
*/}

ensureCapacity: function ensureCapacity() {/*
void ensureCapacity(int)
*/}

size: function size() {/*
int size()
*/}

iterator: function iterator() {/*
java.util.Iterator iterator()
*/}

clear: function clear() {/*
void clear()
*/}

wait: function wait() {/*
void wait()
void wait(long)
void wait(long,int)
*/}

listIterator: function listIterator() {/*
java.util.ListIterator listIterator(int)
java.util.ListIterator listIterator()
*/}

retainAll: function retainAll() {/*
boolean retainAll(java.util.Collection)
*/}

toString: function toString() {/*
java.lang.String toString()
*/}

hashCode: function hashCode() {/*
int hashCode()
*/}

toArray: function toArray() {/*
java.lang.Object[] toArray(java.lang.Object[])
java.lang.Object[] toArray()
*/}

lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() {/*
int lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)
*/}

addAll: function addAll() {/*
boolean addAll(java.util.Collection)
boolean addAll(int,java.util.Collection)
*/}

clone: function clone() {/*
java.lang.Object clone()
*/}

get: function get() {/*
java.lang.Object get(int)
*/}

getClass: function getClass() {/*
java.lang.Class getClass()
*/}

remove: function remove() {/*
java.lang.Object remove(int)
boolean remove(java.lang.Object)
*/}
```

Can anyone tell me how to work with such objects in rhino javascript engine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript program is receiving a Java ArrayList; this is why the above dump matches the API of `java.util.ArrayList`. (See [the Java API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).) You can call the Java methods of that Java object relatively transparently from your JavaScript code. So, for example, to loop through the elements of the array you are receiving:

```
var sku = [however you are getting it];
for (var i=0; i<sku.size(); i++) {
    var nextElement = sku.get(i);
    // do something
}
```

Caveat: Assuming the ArrayList is created on the Java side and is creating Java objects, the algorithm above will put a *Java* `java.lang.String` into the `nextElement` variable. This object may behave strangely if your application is JavaScript-centric (for example, `typeof(nextElement) == "object" /* not "string" */`). If you want a JavaScript string, you'll need to convert it; the easiest way is `String(nextElement)`.